# How to add time to date property? MVC 5 ASP.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, time, datepicker

I've a property in the model:

```
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime eventstart { get; set; }
```

and View:

```
 <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.eventstart, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eventstart, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eventstart, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })               
        </div>
    </div>
```

So I can use jQuery datapicker to choose the date.
As you know if I pick some date then at database will be saved as (for example) **2015-11-14 00:00:00**

Here's the question now. How am i supposed to add time to this property in simple way? Did I have to add new property in model or only next **@Html.TextBox** and then in some way merge both data in controller? Anyway I've no idea how to do it. I need some advice.

**@EDIT**

Ok i found jQuery Picker (http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/#slider_examples).
But it doesn't work. I tried test it in this way:

```
<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.structure.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-slider-access-addon.js"></script>



<input type="text" name="basic_example_1" id="basic_example_1" value="" class="hasDatepicker">

<script>
    $('#basic_example_1').datetimepicker();
</script>
```

And still nothing i see only empty textbox... Did i miss something? (I'm doing this first time)

Comment: `[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]` means your generating `<input type="date" ... />` which renders the HTML5 datepicker, not a jquery datepicker (and its only supported in Chrome). If you want the HTML5 datetimepicker, then you need `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.eventstart, new { type = "datetime" })` but again this is only supported in Chrome. Otherwise use a jquery datetimepicker plugin (there are lots available)

Comment: Ok thank you. I found http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/#slider_examples
Can you tell me how to use it in my project?

Comment: Just include the 3 scripts mentioned in the link, and add a script -  `$('#eventstart').datetimepicker();` (your link has a number of examples)

Comment: <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
<script>$('#eventstarte').datetimepicker();</script>


@Html.TextBox("eventstarte",null,new { @class = "datetimepicker" })

And still doesn't work :(

Comment: You need to edit your question with the new code (not in comments) and if `$('#eventstarte').datetimepicker();` is before `@Html.TextBox("eventstarte" ...)` then, no it wont work - your script referes to an element which does not yet exist in the DOM. Wrap it in document.ready() or place it immediately before the closing `</body>` tag

Comment: Ok i edited post, tell me what is wrong there?

Comment: Why have you got multiple copies of jquery and jquery-ui? (ditto for all the diplicate css files) Just one of each! And what if any errors are you getting in the browser console

Comment: Is now good? (I edited question) But still doesn't work. Should I remove the remaining files from the disk (files that I don't implement) or what?

Comment: You still have duplicate (both the unminified and minified versions). And what errors are you getting in the browser console? And does the version of jquery-ui include the slider widget (you may also need `jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js`)

Comment: I added jquery-ui-slider-access-addon.js (https://gist.github.com/ShivaHuang/3052270) (edited post)

I don't know how to check errors in browser console (chrome) can you show me on screenshot?